# How do i pass the variable from django views.py to my javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Sure, here's a Markdown version of your question for Stack Overflow:

---

#### Issue with Passing Data from Django Views to JavaScript in Template

I'm trying to pass data from my Django view to JavaScript in my template, but I'm encountering an issue where the parameters I'm passing appear to be empty when I inspect the webpage.

##### Views.py

```py
def homepage(request):
    selected_model = request.GET.get('model', '')

    if selected_model == '1':
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'files', 'data', 'preprocessed_price_optimization_dataset.csv'))
        model_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'files', 'data', 'price_optimization_model.h5')

        X = df[['product_id', 'category_id', 'brand_encoded', 'historical_price_scaled']] 
        y = df['historical_price'] 
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

        loaded_model = load_model(model_path)

        predictions = loaded_model.predict(X_test)
        evaluation = loaded_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

        actual_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        predicted_data = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

        context = {
            'actual_data': actual_data,
            'predicted_data': predicted_data,
        }
    else:
        print("no actual and predicted data")
        context = {}

    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

##### base.html

```html
<select id="visualSelector" name="model" onchange="printSelectedValue({{ actual_data|safe }}, {{ predicted_data|safe }})">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">SCATTERPLOT</option>
    <option value="2">LINEPLOT</option>
</select>
```

##### JavaScript

```js
function printSelectedValue(actualData, predictedData) {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('visualSelector').value;
    var selectedModelValue = document.getElementById('modelSelector').value;

    if (selectedModelValue === '0') {
        console.log("No model selected");
        return; 
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('plotCanvas');

    if (selectedValue === '0') {
        canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        console.log("value 0:", actualData);
    } else if (selectedValue === '1') {
        canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        console.log("value 1:", predictedData);
    } else if (selectedValue === '2') {
        canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        console.log("value 2:");
    }
}
```

##### Issue

When inspecting the webpage, the parameters `actualData` and `predictedData` appear to be empty. I've tried using `{{ variablename | safe }}`, but I'm still encountering the same issue.

##### How can I resolve this issue and successfully pass the data from my Django view to JavaScript in my template?

Comment: So... you have a select tag to select your model and an onchange function on it, at the same time the arguments in the onchange depend on a model being selected. How do you suppose this will work? Try to break that into two steps. Call an API when the user selects a model and get the data you need from the API call.

Answer (score 1):

You use the [**`|json_script`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) for this:

```
{{ actual_data|json_script:'actual_data' }}
{{ predicted_data|json_script:'predicted_data' }}

<select id="visualSelector" name="model" onchange="printSelectedValue(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('actual_data').textContent), JSON.parse(document.getElementById('predicted_data').textContent))">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1">SCATTERPLOT</option>
    <option value="2">LINEPLOT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't whether your method is correct or not but according to me:

1. Firstly try printing actual_data & predicted data in if statement (views.py).
2. I would recommend using variables directly into your js script like:

   var actual = "{{actual_data}}";

   alert(actual)
   I hope this simple solution helps you.

Comment: Thanks for replying i fixed it its working now . 
when i printed it in the view.py it was printing 
but when i console.log in the js nothing was printing so their was something wrong with the way i was passing the values .

Comment: Please give me green tick if it helped you...